# Two icon visible on ipad for same application.

Tags: iphone, ipad, icons

Please help me to find a solution. I have one application on iPad. When i download same application ipa file from web url. it display two icons of same application. Please help me out to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: delete both, install again. You will only have 1 icon now :)

Comment: i did this but still i get same icon. I Create a .ipa file for application and then i install. After downloading on ipad display two icon. (e.g old app and new app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you change the `Bundle Identifier`? If so, delete the one with the outdated one.

Answer (score 2):

1. This can happen if both your applications are using different-different Bundle Identifier.
2. There's nothing wrong in that.
3. Just delete both the application and download it again.

Comment: I reset and download this application several time. But i receive same app(2 icon) icon on iPad.Bundle Identifier is same for

Comment: Did you delete both the application before downloading it?

Answer (score 0):

check bundle identifier. and delete all apps associated with that bundle identifier.